# How to implement a local notification in flutter web

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-web, localnotification, flutter-notification

I need to show a notification on flutter web   receiving from an MQQT broker , while chrome is minimized or  is on the other tabs .( like Local Notification in android or ios )

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround I found out was making a js script to show notification and call the javascript show notification function from the flutter app while checking if it is on web or not.

```
// local_notification.js
function showNotification(title, body) {
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notifications");
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    var notification = new Notification(title, {
      body: body,
      icon: "icon.png"
    });

    notification.onclick = function () {
      console.log("Notification clicked");
    };
  } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification(title, {
          body: body,
          icon: "icon.png"
        });

        notification.onclick = function () {
          console.log("Notification clicked");
        };
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Place the following script in the web folder of flutter project and add `<script src="local_notification.js"></script>` at the end of the body tag in `index.html` file. After this I am calling showNotification function like this in flutter

```dart
import 'package:universal_html/js.dart';

if (kIsWeb) {
  context.callMethod("showNotification",["Title","custom message"]);
} else {
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(id,"Title","custom message",notification);
}
```

Works like a charm

Comment: I am trying to implement this. For test purposes i added an AppBar Widget to activate Notifications. The normal Popup: "localhost:61041 wants to show notifications, allow/block" shows up. But i do not get a notification, even after pressing the Show Notification Button several times, do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you check chrome dev console for any errors?

Comment: I moved back to Firebase Notifications, since it is easier, so i do not know what the error was, but thanks for writing back anyways

Comment: Note, `context` can be `window` imported from dart:html, and callMethod can me imported from dart:js_util -> called like `callMethod(window, "showNotification",["Title","custom message"])`

Answer (score -1):

This package supports notifications for most platforms including the **web** too.

Check this out https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications

---

[image]

Comment: There is no support for flutter web yet. It supports only android and ios.